# How do I change my login method from openid to simple email + password?

Tags: support, login

I currently use Yahoo's openid for login to the SE network. I would like to change it to simple email + password based login.

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a StackExchange login under https://stackexchange.com/users/login while being logged in.

With that, you can log in using the email and password form you show.

Comment: But wouldn't that create a new account?

Comment: @RegisteredUser No, it adds a login option to your existing account.

Comment: @RegisteredUser Oh wait, nvm.